# How to Convert datetime from yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00.000 to yyyymmdd and save in a variable

Tags: sql-server

I have a Column `date` of datatype `datetime` which has values `(2017-05-17 00:00:00.000)` now i want to save this datetime as `20170517` to a variable.

i tried this:

```
declare @AAA VARCHAR(50)
 select @AAA = convert(varchar, @Date, 112)
```

but it returns `May 17 2017 12:00AM`

Comment: What returns `May 17 2017 12:00AM`? `SELECT @AAA;` returns `20170517`.

Comment: the code above doesn't actually return _anything_, it just sets the variable. But if you then select that variable for display as Larnu says, you get the value you're expecting. Whatever your problem is, it's not in this bit of the code.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked fine:

```
declare @aaa varchar(50)
SELECT @AAA= FORMAT( @Date, 'yyyyMMdd', 'en-US' )
select @AAA=  REPLACE(@AAA,'-','')
```

Comment: Ok, but the code in your question also produces the same output (if you just add `select @aaa` as the last line of it), so it's hard to see what the original issue is.